# Geometric structure of atomic nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics

The electrons in an atom have a certain configuration and we can predict in which space the electrons can be present of a certain energy level (s-orbitals have a sphere-shape,....).

Recently I read that there are [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28physics%29) for nuclei: special configurations of the nuclei that makes them more stable (the magic numbers are 2, 8, 20, 28, 34, 50, 82, and 126) - so there are definitely [shells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model) in a nucleus. I was wondering : do the neutrons and protons form certain geometric structures in these sub-shells of the nucleus?

Or are they all stacked closely on each other?